# Eager loading an optional one-to-one with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, one-to-one, select-n-plus-1

Consider the following simplified domain:

```
public class Movie
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual MovieDetail MovieDetail { get; set; }
}

public class MovieDetail
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
}
```

A `MovieDetail` cannot exist without a `Movie`, but a `Movie` could exist without a `MovieDetail` (i.e. we have no details about it).

Our database has a separate table for `Movie` with columns `Id`, and a separate table for `MovieDetail` with columns `Id` and `MovieId`. There is also a foreign key from `MovieDetail.MovieId` to `Movie.Id`.

We've got this all mapped in NHibernate, but when getting a collection of `Movie` instances, we want a left outer join with `MovieDetail`. If not, we could have a N+1 problem when iterating over the `Movie` instances. That is the case now: there is a separate query for every call to the `Movie.MovieDetail` property.

I've tried `one-to-one` mapping, but that seems to be for the case when you have both instances. In our case, we don't always have a `MovieDetail`. Also, they don't share the same primary key.

I've researched formula's, but that would require me to make my `MovieDetail` implement `IUserType`, essentially putting NHibernate into my domain. I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try adding a many-to-one relation in the `Movie` mapping to `MovieDetail`, it will act as a one to one mapping.

When you set the option 'not-null' to "false" it is also nullable I suppose.
I don't know if you are lazy loading or not, when this is so the `MovieDetail`is loaded when needed and not by a left join construction.

Shouldn't all the properties be virtual in both classes?

```
<many-to-one name="MovieDetail" column="Id" class="MovieDetail" not-null="false" lazy="false"/>
```

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. Possibly, our domain has something exotic (I did simplify it). Properties should indeed be virtual (they were).

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a bit of a hurry and I don't know if you can modify your domain / db schema but you might want to try and take a look at http://ayende.com/blog/3937/nhibernate-mapping-component.

It seems to me that a `Movie` can have at most one `MovieDetail` which might not be there. `MovieDetail` might have properties like `Description`, `ReleaseDate`, `Actors`, etc. I don't really understand why you separated these concepts. By bringing them together you would have 1 less table and 1 less FK to join on each time you want to list movies.

The component allows you to isolate your data into a separate entity while mapping to the same table as `Movie`.

Comment: Well it was a simplified domain/schema. The real thing has its reason it is so, but I simplified/anonimized it.